# Unable to move an element using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

This is my markup:

```
<button class="left" ng-mousedown="moveLeft()">Left</button>
```

This is my code:

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller("wallControl", function($scope) {

    var leftTimer;

    $scope.mousePress = function() {
        moveLeft();
    };

    var moveLeft = function() {
        if (circleX > 0) {
            circleX -= 4;
        }
        leftInterval = $timeout(moveLeft, 1000);
    };

    $scope.mouseRelease = function() {
        $timeout.cancel(leftTimer);
    };
});
```

There are no errors in the console. Why is the variable `circleX` not changing? I have never used Angular before so I might have made a silly mistake.

Comment: This really isn't a question about Angular or Ionic. Have you stepped through your function to track the value of `circleX`?

Comment: how can you say about no errors? there is not injected $timeout and moveLeft is not in $scope ,

Comment: @Pravat-MujahMaskey angular doesn't make an error if you try to call an undefined function from `ng-mousedown` directive.  And because `moveLeft` is not ever being called, the attempt to call `$timeout` is never reached. ;)

Comment: @plong0, yes you are right ;) , (y) , but it will complain about "circleX" variable if you bind to correct method, thanks for correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you are calling `mouseLeft()`, but that function is not exposed on `$scope`.

Another problem is that you never assign anything to `leftTimer`.

Another problem is that you don't inject `$timeout`.

I would try something like:

```
<button class="left" ng-mousedown="mousePress()" ng-mouseup="mouseRelease()">Left</button>
```

and

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

// notice the DI syntax (which is not only a best practice, but is necessary if you minify your code)
// notice $interval service is injected
.controller("wallControl", ['$scope', '$interval', function($scope, $interval) {

    // used to store the $interval handle so it can be cancelled
    var leftTimer;

    $scope.mousePress = function() {
        // start running moveLeft every 1000ms
        leftTimer = $interval(moveLeft, 1000);
    };

    var moveLeft = function() {
        if (circleX > 0) {
            circleX -= 4;
        }
        // no need to call itself on $timeout - $interval doing that
    };

    $scope.mouseRelease = function() {
        // stop the moveLeft interval
        $interval.cancel(leftTimer);
    };
}]);
```

**Update: Multiple-Directions**

Pretty straight-forward with a couple small changes to code really.  I've gone a step further and elaborated on a couple other concepts to make the code slightly more realistic.

```
<button class="left" ng-mousedown="startMoveX(-1)" ng-mouseup="stopMoveX()">Left</button>
<button class="right" ng-mousedown="startMoveX(1)" ng-mouseup="stopMoveX()">Right</button>
```

and

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller("wallControl", ['$scope', '$interval', function($scope, $interval) {
    // some settings (magic numbers are bad m'kay)
    var xSpeed = 4;
    var xBounds = { min: 0, max: 1000 };

    // circleX need to be defined somewhere
    // how you will use it for drawing is another story
    var circleX = (xBounds.min + xBounds.max) / 2.0;

    // x-motion variables
    var xMoveTimer;
    var xDirection;

    // starts the x-motion
    $scope.startMoveX = function(direction) {
        // track which direction to move (used as multiplier on speed)
        xDirection = direction;

        // make sure the xMoveTimer is not already running
        if(!xMoveTimer){
            // start running moveX every 1000ms
            xMoveTimer = $interval(moveX, 1000);
        }
    };

    // stops the x-motion
    $scope.stopMoveX = function() {
        if(xMoveTimer){
            // stop it
            $interval.cancel(xMoveTimer);

            // release it
            xMoveTimer = undefined;
        }
    };

    // performs the x-motion
    var moveX = function() {
        // move it move it
        circleX += xSpeed * xDirection;

        // lock it to bounds
        if(circleX < xBounds.min){
            circleX = xBounds.min;
        }
        else if(circleX > xBounds.max){
            circleX = xBounds.max;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks @plong0.  Do I have to write the same code again for a right button?

Comment: Haha, I knew that was going to be the next question.  Anyway, I just updated my answer with a left + right button and renamed a couple things in the controller to make it all more logical.

Comment: I figured it out last night but there was a lot of duplication in my case :)

Comment: Do you have any idea why the response time is slow on mobile devices? I have to keep the button pressed for quite some time to move the circle.

Comment: well a 1000ms delay is a full second wait between each tick.  quite a long time between animation frames really.  If you wanted say "60 frames per second", you would make the `$interval` delay `(1000 / 60)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are attempting to bind the event to a function and the `$scope` is unaware of the function, it won't work.  You need to add the function to the `$scope`, i.e `$scope.moveLeft = (){ ... }`

That or change your `ng-mousedown` binding to the scope function you declared already `$scope.mousepress() { ... }`

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I had one more doubt. After changing `ng-mousedown="moveLeft()"` to `ng-mousedown="mousePress"` I got the error about `$timeout` not defined. What is `$timeout` supposed to be? I thought it is a term in AngularJS for `setTimeout`. I have updated the code now to `setTimeout(moveLeft, 10);` but what was `$timeout(moveLeft, 1000);` above supposed to be?

Comment: I am sorry if it was a stupid question. I am just super new to all this.